# Disabling selection on Android if listChoiceBackgroundIndicator item style is used

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, android-styles

I have a [`ListView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/) and I disabled the [selection](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Selection_Taps) with:

```cs
void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
  }
  ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

In my Android theme I have defined the following in my style

```xml
<item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@color/primaryLight</item>
```

If I do this the item stays visually selected, despite the selected state is unselected.

The goal is to have a styling, which works for both types: selectable and not selectable list view items. If I use `((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;` the background for presenting the selected state should go back to default.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((ListView)sender).requestLayout();
((ListView)sender).clearChoices();
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that `requestLayout()` and `clearChoices()` aren't available in Xamarin.Forms `ListView`. Even [platform-specifics](https://blog.xamarin.com/bringing-platform-specific-functionality-to-xamarin-forms-apps/) doesn't seem to support that methods for `ListView`. Perhaps a custom renderer would do that. So there is no option to use styling only?

Comment: You hadn't mentioned that you are using Xamarin. I have no experience with it. However, I think you can do this using styling.

Comment: Sometimes I have to take the Xamarin approach, sometimes the native Android one. So an Android only solution could also work (or I can translate that to Xamarin).